# error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] in a Lambda function

Tags: c++, c++17

```
vector<string>::iterator newEnd=unique(newstring.begin(),newstring.end(),[](const char &a,const char &b){return a==b && a==" "; });
newstring.erase(newEnd,newstring.end());
```

I've been trying to run this piece of code and it's giving me an error on the lambda function.

> error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

This was working in HackerRank for a function called `split_strings()`. Can anyone please help me solve it?

My intention is to remove all the spaces in a space-separated string, and return a pointer to the last element of the changed array.

Comment: `vector<string>::iterator newEnd=` -- Use `auto newEnd = `, so as to avoid declaring the wrong return type.

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` are the same type, but `" "` is not a character, it is used for string literals.  Consider changing to `return a==b && a==' ';`

Answer (score 1):

You actually have *two* problems:

1. The first is the error you get, which is because of `a==" "`, where you compare a single `char` variable (`a`) with a string literal. To compare to a single space you need to compare to the *character* `' '`.
2. The second error is either that you use the wrong iterator for `newEnd` or that you use the wrong types for the comparison lambdas.

   If `newstring` is a `std::string` then the lambda is correct, it should take two characters as arguments. The problem is that then `std::unique` will return a `std::string::iterator`.

   If `newstring` is a `std::vector<string>` then the arguments to the lambda are `std::string` values. The `newEnd` iterator will be correct though.

---

Lastly, to remove all spaces in a string then [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) seems rather bad choice (especially since it's supposed to remove *duplicates*).

I would rather recommend [`std::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), as in:

```
newstring.erase(std::erase(begin(newstring), end(newstring), ' '), end(newstring));
```